# Relative layout with layout_gravity=right shrinks containing TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reason Relative Layout with gravity set to "right" doesn't stop with its gravity on the longest widget, instead it goes till the shortest one, moving the longest to the right.

Here is an image to explain it better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/POHmA.png

I want it to stop pulling gravity to the right when it reaches the @id/timestampTextView, i.e. i want "some long long long long text" to be displayed fully, without hiding. Moreover, I want it to respect android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textTextView", i.e. the "some long long long long text" should be right-aligned with "short text".

Here is the layout for that image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_light">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timestampTextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:text="some long long long long text"
           android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textTextView"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Funny thing is that setting layout_gravity to the left and android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textTextView" instead of alignRight, it works correctly for the left side, but I need it to work similarly for the right side. Why the same thing doesn't work for the right side?

Here are image and code for the left side displaying correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i4yG.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_light">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timestampTextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:text="some long long long long text"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textTextView"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

Solved this by replacing RelativeLayout with LinearLayout: i.stack.imgur.com/dD5TL.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/messageLinearLayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_light">

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="some long long long long text"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:layout_gravity="right" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textTextView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="short text"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:layout_gravity="right" />

       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:layout_alignRight attribute for TextView with id textTextView instead of TextView with id timestampTextView. See below. I think it is not the best way but it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_light">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="short text"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/timestampTextView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timestampTextView" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:text="some long long long long text"
           android:textSize="10sp" />

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use at least 12sp textSize

Comment: But I want the relative layout to wrap the text views, i.e. I want it to start right before the @id/timestampTextView, where the red line is on this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2cer.png, similar to what it was in http://i.stack.imgur.com/POHmA.png, but without hiding the @id/timestampTextView.

Comment: @JohnBerger I edited the answer. I think there should be better solution but maybe it is sufficient for you for now.

Comment: @JohnBerger Did my answer help you somehow?

Comment: Not really. I switched from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout, that solved my problem. Here is my layout final layout http://pastebin.com/HFnWneH3

Comment: @JohnBerger OK, it is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timestampTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timestampTextView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="short text"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestampTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="some long long long long text"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I want the relative layout to wrap the text views, i.e. I want it to start right before the @id/timestampTextView, where the red line is on this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2cer.png, similar to what it was in http://i.stack.imgur.com/POHmA.png, but without hiding the @id/timestampTextView.